# HTTP/2 client - associate response to request - can rely on stream id?

Tags: java, netty, http2

I'm trying to use `netty` to implement HTTP/2 client. In this [example](https://github.com/fstab/http2-examples/blob/master/multiplexing-examples/netty-client/src/main/java/de/consol/labs/h2c/examples/client/netty/Http2Client.java) (line 93) they manually increment `streamId` and put it to the map. When response comes they look for `HttpConversionUtil.ExtensionHeaderNames.STREAM_ID` header parameter and thus associate the response with the request.

I don't like the idea of increasing `streamId` by myself. Can I somehow get the id netty's going to use to `writeAndFlush` the request?

Also, does it take much resources to create a new stream? Or is it just an identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, at this moment you can't get `streamId` generated and used by Netty. Also, I don't like the idea of increasing `streamId` by myself too, but looks like it's okay to do this with current API.

I've checked Netty sources and found next things:

1. [HttpToHttp2ConnectionHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/codec-http2/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http2/HttpToHttp2ConnectionHandler.java) is used for writing requests. It has private method `getStreamId` which is used in `write` method for getting value of `currentStreamId`. But we doesn't have any access to this variable.
2. `getStreamId` method uses another method called [incrementAndGetNextStreamId](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/codec-http2/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http2/DefaultHttp2Connection.java#L674). So, again, we can only increment and get new `streamId` value but can't get the current one.

Both of these classes marked with annotation `@UnstableApi`, so maybe this behavior will be change in the future.

Here's some related links:

1. [A little bit updated HTTP 2 client example from Netty repository](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http2/helloworld/client).
2. [HTTP/2 Java Client Examples](http://unrestful.io/2015/10/10/http2-java-client-examples.html).
3. [Why netty http2 server always use odd number for streamId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550116/why-netty-http2-server-always-use-odd-number-for-streamid).

Comment: So I decided not to rely on streamId and asked serverside-developers to read special header ("X-id" for example) from the request and put it into response.

Comment: I think, it's not very critical, but also not so good. The main disadvantage is that now all API clients must keep in mind, that they should provide `X-Id` in request and get it from response. However, maybe it's ok for high concurrency API, because this can work even with HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Yea, it's an ad-hoc solution for the concrete project, but I found no way to implement it better